# Ubuntu desktop entry

Tags: 14.04, .desktop

I have a *.desktop item in `/usr/share/applications` folder, but it's still is not available via search in Ubuntu `"Type to search"`results.
What should I do to make concrete desktop item to be available in search?

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion? Please give an example...

Comment: @George, I have `IntelliJ IDEA` file in `/usr/share/applications` folder. But I cant see it in search result for `Type to search` window , when I try to type some combination like "idea" or "intellij" - it shows me nothing.

Comment: That's because its has a different name  than what you typed...in that location

Comment: @George, and what should I type to find it?

Comment: Let me check that

Comment: try name "jetbrains"

Comment: @George, empty from "jetbrains"

Comment: Please check in the `~/.local/share/applications` folder and use word `jetbrains`

Comment: @George, jetbrains gives 0 results

Comment: Found it pls check in `/usr/local/share/applications/` and that's where jetbrain hides it since I had instructed it to create for all users

Comment: TO find yours use the search command `sudo find / -type f -iname "jetbrains-*"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetbrains appears not to install their `.desktop` files in the normal locations as I discovered. One would expect them to be found here `/usr/share/applicatiosn` but rather I found several locations where these files are stored.

If you instruct `Jetbrains` software to install desktop for all users then the location is:

```
/usr/local/share/applications
```

If you instructed it to just install for you alone then the location is:

```
/home/$USER/.local/share/applications
```

Now I also found it here:

```
/home/$USER/.gnome/apps
```

That being said one can search for them using the command:

```
sudo find / -type f -iname "jetbrains-*"
```

Comment: It's ok, I really have desktop item in my `/usr/share/applications` as I **mentioned in my answer**, but the question was **why it still is not available via search in Ubuntu "Type to search"results**

Comment: Are you talking above about Dash search?

Comment: yes exactly about it

Comment: Please open Intellij and click menu `tools --> Create Desktop Entry` then you will see the option to create for all users, select this if you like. With this option every account will see this desktop launcher, now click `Create`. Launcher should appear in `Dash`, restart the system if it still doesn't appear in the `Dash`